# Is batchWriteItem of dynamoDB (Javascript sdk) deprecated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am trying to use **batchWriteItem** in dynamoDB to perform more than one put requests. I am using **v2.6.8** of **aws-sdk** inside a lambda function. It gives me a weird error: batchWriteItem is not a function. Having said, put and get works fine!! Any idea what am I missing ?

Comment: No it's not deprecated. The documentation is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#batchWriteItem-property if it was deprecated it would say so in the documentation. Also, if it was deprecated you would not be getting an error message like that. That error message would mean it had been completely removed from the SDK, not just deprecated. I think you need to show your code so we can help you further. Check how you are calling the `batchWriteItem` function.

Answer (score 16):

I inspected the dynamoDb object, turns out the method name is **batchWrite**

Answer (score 4):

If you init like this `const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(options)`, then BatchWrite is the correct funciton. Visit https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#batchWrite-property

If you init like this `const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB(options)`, then you can use BatchWriteItem without problems